# Нативная реализация LDAP/AD для golang

Tags: golang, active-directory, ldap

Может кто встречал реализацию LDAP/AD для golang с возможностью бинда/поиска.
Из всего что я нашёл поддержка флага *secured = true* есть только в github.com/paleg/libadclient, но это враппер, и по ряду причин он не подходит.
Попробовал gopkg.in/ldap.v2 , но видимо в нём нет поддержки AD, потому что постоянно вываливается ошибка ***Invalid Credentials***, гугл говорит что такая ошибка бывает если пытатся подключится к AD без параметра **secured**, бинд к простому LDAP проходит нормально.
Ещё одна либа github.com/mavricknz/ldap как я понял тоже не поддерживает **secured**
ps: пароли правильные при бинде к AD правильные, единственное не знаю нужно ли писать полный путь до аккаунта со всеми ou или достаточно только *cn=username,dc=example,dc=com*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге смог разобраться с *gopkg.in/ldap.v2*
Авторизация проходит если делать **bind** с именем пользователя *username@mydomain.com* вместо *"cn=username,dc=mydomain,dc=com"*